# Split a string into a character array - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am building a PygLatin App and would like to know how to split a string into a character array.

For example:

If the user inputs "hello world" I would want to be able to split `hello` into an array variable that stores it as `[@"h",@"e",@"l",@"l",@"o"]` so that I can compare it with the vowels array later.

Answer (score -1):

Those functions must help you to do it.

```
NSString *str=@"hello world";  // your string
NSArray *items = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; //split string with separator 
NSString *str1=[items objectAtIndex:0]; // get the first string 
SString *str2=[items objectAtIndex:1];

for (int i=0; i < [str1 length]; i++) {
unichar mycharacter = [str1 characterAtIndex:0];
NSString * mycharasstring= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", mycharacter];
[self.myarray addobject: [myString characterAtIndex:i]];  // add characters to your array 

}
```

Comment: This won't work for any Unicode character with a code of U+10000 or greater (such as Emoji and others).

Comment: @rmaddy yes sure its just a simple solution for simple string , he didn't ask about complexe data i think !! can u provide us a better solution that resolve this problem ? im a student trying to help and get better :)

Comment: See the answers in the duplicate question. BTW - not my down vote.

Comment: no problem , i deserve it  !!

Comment: You can't use `addObject:` with the return value of `characterAtIndex:` A `unichar` is not an object, it's a primitive. You would have to construct a new string from the individual character.

Comment: i need to parse it to NSString ?

Comment: @JoshCaswell ,Thank you , i got it :))

Comment: You might have a look at [the "Splitting" example in Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/objective-c/832/nsstring/3828/splitting)